# SVN update via svn instead of http protocol

Tags: svn

How can I  update via svn protocol ? instead of http ? I know how to checkout via svn:// but  `$svn update` doesn't let you specify the protocol and it is using the one you did checkout with

I'm getting

```
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (413 Request Entity Too Large) in response to REPORT request for '/repos/public/!svn/vcc/default'
```

And I remember that last time using svn:// helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've done a checkout with the http:// protocol, you're 'stuck'. You can either use svn switch --relocate to point to the svn:// url, or create a fresh checkout

Comment: works, thanks man... However, I don't know why would you say that I'm stuck and then come up with correct working solution ?

Comment: well, I just meant you can't just use a different url without fully switching your working copy first ;)